# Where to add page meta entries

Tags: dxa, java, dxa-java

In DXA Java 1.4 in the page a list of

```
<c:forEach var="meta" items="${pageModel.meta.entrySet()}">
<meta name="${meta.key}" content="${meta.value}">
</c:forEach>
```

Is there in the CME a way to add a value to that list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these `PageModel.meta` values are derived from CM Page Metadata (and other things).

See the `processPageMetadata` implementation in PageBuilderImpl:
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/master/dxa-framework/dxa-tridion-provider/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/tridion/mapping/PageBuilderImpl.java

Comment: Thanks Rick, for this I create a custom meta data schema that editors can fill in. What if I want to add it to all pages, should I do it in the views then ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. If you have HTML meta values which are the same for all Pages (of a given type), you can hard-code those in the associated Page View(s).